# Do While entra em loop infinito

Tags: java, while, condição

Tenho certeza que meu erro está no `while`, mas não consigo entender o que fiz de errado. Ele entra em *loop* infinito.

Segue o enunciado:

> Implemente um programa que receba da linha de comando 3 argumentos. O
>   primeiro e o segundo argumento são números reais e o terceiro argumento é a
>   operação.

Segue o código:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Argumentos {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        float resultado = 0;

        System.out.println("Insira um valor: ");
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        float num1 = scanner1.nextFloat();

        System.out.println("Insira outro valor: ");
        Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        float num2 = scanner2.nextFloat();

        System.out.println("Insira a operação (+, -, / ou *): ");


        System.out.println("Insira a operação (+, -, / ou *): ");
        Scanner c = new Scanner(System.in);
        char operacao = c.next().charAt(0);

        do {

            if(operacao == '*') {
                resultado = (num1*num2);
            } else if (operacao == '/') {
                resultado = (num1/num2);
            } else if (operacao == '+') {
                resultado = (num1+num2);
            } else if (operacao == '-') {
                resultado = (num1-num2);
            }

            System.out.println("Insira a operação (+, -, / ou *): ");
            operacao = c.next().charAt(0);

            System.out.println("Resultado da conta: " + resultado);

        } while((operacao != '*') || (operacao != '/') || (operacao != '-') || (operacao != '+'));

        System.out.println("Resultado da conta: " + resultado);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

É infinito porque essa expressão sempre será verdadeira:

```
while((operacao != '*') || (operacao != '/') || (operacao != '-') || (operacao != '+'));
```

Vamos pegar a primeira comparação:

```
operacao != '*'
```

Consideremos que `operacao` valha `*`. Por ser igual o resultado seria `false`, já que está perguntando se é diferente.

Aí vamos olhar para a seguinte comparação?

```
operacao != '/'
```

Já sabemos que `operacao` vale `*`, portanto só existe uma hipótese de resultado aí e é `true`, `*` é diferente de `/`.

Nem precisa avaliar as demais comparações porque já se tem um resultado final para toda expressão, afinal quando se usar `||` há um *short circuit* porque basta um dos operandos do "OR" ser verdadeiro, que o todo será verdadeiro.

Provavelmente deseja isso:

```
while (operacao != '*' && operacao != '/' && operacao != '-' && operacao != '+');
```

Assim só continuar se todas as quatro comparações forem verdadeiras, ou seja, se nenhum desses caracteres foi digitado.

Tudo isso [pode ser observado na tabela verdade](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabela_verdade).

Seria mais ou menos isso:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Argumentos {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float resultado = 0;
        System.out.println("Insira um valor: ");
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        float num1 = scanner1.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Insira outro valor: ");
        Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        float num2 = scanner2.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Insira a operação (+, -, / ou *): ");
        Scanner c = new Scanner(System.in);
        char operacao = c.next().charAt(0);
        do {
            if (operacao == '*') {
                resultado = num1 * num2;
            } else if (operacao == '/') {
                resultado = num1 / num2;
            } else if (operacao == '+') {
                resultado = num1 + num2;
            } else if (operacao == '-') {
                resultado = num1 - num2;
            }
            System.out.println("Insira a operação (+, -, / ou *): ");
            operacao = c.next().charAt(0);
            System.out.println("Resultado da conta: " + resultado);
        } while (operacao != '*' && operacao != '/' && operacao != '-' && operacao != '+');
        System.out.println("Resultado da conta: " + resultado);
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/Calculator.java).

Dá até para simplificar um pouco.

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi direito seu objetivo é executar as operações enquanto o usuário entra com um código da operação, seja ele `'+'`, `'-'`, `'/'` ou `'*'`.

Se for isso, seu `do while` está invertido. O correto é algo como: *"Faça isso, enquanto o que for digitado for igual a isso."*

Você esta fazendo: *"Faça isso, enquanto o que for digitado for diferente disso."*

Logo, seu código ficaria assim

```
//...
do {
   if(operacao == '*') {
      resultado = (num1*num2);
   } else if (operacao == '/') {
      resultado = (num1/num2);
   } else if (operacao == '+') {
      resultado = (num1+num2);
   } else if (operacao == '-') {
      resultado = (num1-num2);
   }
   System.out.println("Insira a operação (+, -, / ou *): ");
   operacao = c.next().charAt(0);
   System.out.println("Resultado da conta: " + resultado);
} while((operacao == '*') || (operacao == '/') || (operacao == '-') || (operacao == '+'));
//..
```